# Chilkat: Problem to sign document with Belgium eid in Windows 10 64b

Tags: c++, chilkat

There is a long time that i'm using Chilkat to sign crypt, ... without any problem.
But now I have some problems with it on Windows 10 (64b) to make a sign file with belgium id (it work on windows 10 32b). the soft doesn't ask for pin code, so it s impossible to sign

I tried to upgrade to latest version of chilkat (I have a licence for a old one), I updated the eid middleware, but no success.
I tried with an other soft, and don't have problems to sign.

here is my code:

```
CkCrypt2 crypt;
CkCsp csp;
crypt.UnlockComponent("Start my 30-day Trial");

CkCreateCS ccs;
CkCertStore *p_certStore = 0;
ccs.put_ReadOnly(true);
p_certStore = ccs.OpenCurrentUserStore();
CkCert *p_cert = 0;

CkString ckS1;
CkString ckS2;

p_cert = p_certStore->FindCertBySerial(csCertSerialNumber);
delete p_certStore;

success = csp.SetProviderMicrosoftEnhanced();
success = csp.SetProviderMicrosoftStrong();
success = csp.SetProviderMicrosoftRsaAes();
iCount = csp.SetHashAlgorithm("sha-1");
    //crypt.SetCSP(&csp);
    crypt.SetCSP(csp);
    crypt.put_IncludeCertChain(false);

    iCount = csp.get_NumSignatureAlgorithms();
    for(i=0;i<iCount;i++)
        {
        csp.NthSignatureAlgorithm(i,ckS1);
        csAlgorithm.Format("%s",ckS1);
        }
crypt.SetSigningCert(*p_cert);  

success = crypt.CreateP7S(csFileToSign,csSignatureFile);
```

And on windows 10 64b, I can't put my pin code, and crypt failed

As error, I received: 
Failed to sign.
secStatus: 0x106
Does anyone have an idea to help me?

Comment: Which function gave an error? Did you look it up in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version of Chilkat w/ the CkCert::LoadFromSmartcard method.

https://www.example-code.com/cpp/load_certificate_on_smartcard_in_reader.asp

You may also be able to set the PIN programmatically as shown here: https://www.example-code.com/cpp/cades_bes_smartcard.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't solve my problem.If I use the second proposition I can have the good certififcate (set the pin prog).
But as you can read in the comment:
// If the PIN is not explicitly provided here, the Windows OS should
    // display a dialog for the PIN.
My problem is that the OS don't display the dialog :( as I need